# Adapt image size for iphone

Tags: css

I collapsed with problem that devtools for mobile looks ok, but when I open project on iphone main image crashes and appeared only 1/4 of its size. Which properties I should add to make it adaptive on iphone?

Here is css code:

```css
.main-page__background {
  background-image: url("../../../images/main.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
  background-color: #2a2c2f;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could resize your image for mobile screens and make a copy of it, then change the background image in a media query.

```
@media(max-width: 400px){background-image: url("../../../images/new smaller image");}
```